# Operate on variables in Bash directly in a loop

Tags: bash, variables, indirection

My googlefu is failing me. I have a bunch of variables I read it from a CSV where I want to strip whitespace. I could

```sh
variable1="$(echo -e "${variable1}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"
variable2="$(echo -e "${variable2}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"
variable3="$(echo -e "${variable3}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"
```

but then I'm copying in and editing this for every variable change. It seems to me, from other languages, there should be a way to do a simple for loop that applies to the variables as named and strips the whitespace, but I can't figure out exactly how to do that.

```sh
for $i in variable1 variable2 variable3
do
$i=$(echo -e "${$i}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')
done
```

but this doesn't work as far as I can tell. What I want to do is loop over all the variables, strip whitespace, but not have to manually type out each variable name in the script.

Comment: Please note that in shell code variable names are only `$`-prefixed when you _reference_ a variable, not when you _define_/_assign to_ it; thus, it should be `for i in ...` and `i=$(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
# Sample values that need trimming.
variable1='  a  '
variable2='      b  c  '
variable3='        sadf sdf sdf     '

for name in ${!variable*}; do
  # Trim leading and trailing whitespace.
  read -r $name <<<"${!name}"
  # Print result
  echo "Variable $name now contains: [${!name}]"
done
```

The solution relies on [*variable indirection*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Indirection), the ability to refer to a variable *indirectly*, via *another* variable containing the target variable's name.

<sup>Note that variable indirection has its pitfalls (see link) and that there often better solutions, e.g., through use of arrays.</sup>

- `${!variable*}` expands to the names of all defined variables whose name starts with `variable`.
- `${!name}` expands to the value of the variable whose name is stored in variable `$name`.
- `read -r`, by virtue of reading into a *single* variable, implicitly trims leading and trailing whitespace.

  - `-r` ensures that `\` chars. in the input are left alone, which is typically what you want.